# Are innovations $0$ for the first term in a differenced series?

Tags: time-series, self-study, arima, seasonality

I'm working on an unassessed course problem,

> Consider a time series consisting of quarterly observations of temperature in a city. The seasonally differenced time series $\{x_t\}$ with $D=1$ is modelled with an $\text{ARMA}(1,1)$ process $$x_t=1+\frac{1}{3}x_{t-1}+\epsilon_t+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{t-1},$$ where $\epsilon_t$ is white noise with variance $2$.
>
> Two year data (8 observations in total) on the time series $\{y_t\}$ are provided in the next table. $$\begin{matrix}t&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\ y_t&7&15&19&9&8&13&20&7\end{matrix}$$
> Based on the data above, provide a $95$% predictive interval of $x_{10}$.

The seasonally differenced time series should be $$x_t=(1-B^4)^1y_t=y_t-y_{t-4}.$$

The answer booklet contains the line (edited for clarity)

> We need to compute $\epsilon_8$. We back-track from $\epsilon_6$: \begin{align}
> \epsilon_6
> & = x_6&&-1&&-\frac{1}{3}x_5&&-\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_5 \\
> & = (y_6-y_2)&&-1&&-\frac{1}{3}(y_5-y_1)&&-\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_5 \\
> & = (13-15)&&-1&&-\frac{1}{3}(8-7)&&-\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_5 \\
> & = -2&&-1&&-\frac{1}{3}\times1&&-\frac{1}{2}\times\color{red}{0} \\
> & = -\frac{10}{3}.
> \end{align}

Why does $\epsilon_5=0$? Is it because $x_5$ is the first $x_t$ defined? If so, why should that follow? Perhaps the first defined term in a differenced series is conventionally assigned an innovation of $0$.

Comment: Adding parentheses to the calculation would help in following our interpretation as well as your interpretation. Regardless. the origin of the timeline is based on a lagged value., therefore *0* for the first term makes sense.

Comment: @MikeHunter So is the innovation of the first term of a lagged series conventionally defined to be $0$? I'm not sure why that should be, but if it's a convention I can accept it.

Comment: Yes, a *convention* driven by empirical fact. Think about it. If you have eight first-differenced observations, what happens to the first term in that series? From an analytic perspective that first observation is sacrificed, is it not?

Comment: @MikeHunter Do you mean eight observations taken as the basis for a first-differenced series of seven terms? If that's what you mean, I agree the first term is sacrificed. My question is about the innovation on the first defined term, i.e. the term following the last sacrificed term. For that term I'm not sure why the innovation should be defined as $0$, but I could accept such a convention if it exists.

Comment: Again, I can't be the only one confused by the presentation of the equation. It would really help if the question were edited to include parentheses around the terms.

Comment: @MikeHunter I've edited the quote from the answer booklet. Is that the sort of thing you had in mind?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147599/discussion-between-mike-hunter-and-mjc).